# Blazor inline rendering weirdness

Tags: c#, blazor

I am using Blazor Bootstrap and trying to update the page after a submission of a form. The Form simply creates a DB entry and is returned with a true or false. The page is using Tabs with Disabled being set depending on whether the user has submitted the form. Here is the code:

```
private void CreateNewTeam()
{
    OwnedTeam.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var TeamModel = new Data.Models.Teams()
        {
            TeamName = OwnedTeam.TeamName,
            TeamLogo = OwnedTeam.TeamLogo,
            TeamLeader = OwnedTeam.TeamLeader,
            ID = OwnedTeam.Id
        };

    bool Created = TeamService.CreateTeam(TeamModel);
    if (Created)
    {
        TeamsMessages.Add(CreateToastMessage(ToastType.Success, "New Team created."));
        teamCreated = true;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
    else
    {
        TeamsMessages.Add(CreateToastMessage(ToastType.Danger, "No Team created. If the issue persists contact admin."));
    }
}
```

The boolean is set on page load to be false:

```
private bool teamCreated = false;
```

And then on InitalizedAsync checks to see if there is anything active in the DB for that user:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    TeamInformation = TeamService.GetTeamInformation();
    var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authstate.User;
    if (user?.Identity?.Name != null)
    {
        isAuthenticated = true;
        isMemberofAnyTeam = TeamInformation.Any(x => x.TeamMembers.Contains(user.Identity.Name));
        OwnedTeam = TeamInformation.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TeamLeader == user.Identity.Name)!;

        if (OwnedTeam == null)
        {
            OwnedTeam = new TeamListing { TeamLeader = user.Identity.Name };
        }
        teamCreated = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(OwnedTeam.TeamName);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I submit the form the the disabled isn't being removed until I move away from the page and come back. Here is the Blazor page details:

```
<Tab Title="Create Team" Disabled="@(teamCreated)">
                <Content>
                    <EditForm Model="@OwnedTeam" OnValidSubmit="CreateNewTeam">
                        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                        <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="OwnedTeam.TeamName" Placeholder="Team Name" />
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => OwnedTeam.TeamName)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 10px">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Create New Team</button>
                        </div>
                    </EditForm>
                </Content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab Title="Manage Team" Disabled="@(!teamCreated)">
                <Content>
                    <div class="justify-content-center team-container">
                        <Card Class="team-card">
                            <-- ommited for brevity -->
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                </Content>
            </Tab>
```

I'm sure there's something stupid going on but I cannot figure it out so any help would be appreciated. It only happens on submission of the form, it's like it's not being re-rendered properly and as I say if I move away or do anything else it works perfectly. For example I have another tab on this page and just click on that is enough to get the page to work it's magic.

Comment: That's look like something simple `StateHasChanged()` call on the end of your submit method can fix. Is it server, or wasm? Or ssr only?

Comment: Yeah I thought that too which is why I did have it in there but research suggested that it should be InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); which is currently in there either way. Neither of these fixed the issue. There is some modifications that I think I can make to the Tabs service so I'm going to try that and will report back.

Comment: Does you tab have something like `@bind-Disabled` instead of `Disabled="@(teamCreated)"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a few changes to the way the system worked. In the end to get around this issue I took a very blunt force approach and implemented this line of code at the end of the submission function within Razor:

MyNavigationManager.NavigateTo(MyNavigationManager.Uri, forceLoad: true);